# script running manually, but fails when set as crontab

Tags: java, cron

I have a script `log.sh` which runs a jar `Logger.jar`. This jar reads from a property file `logger.xml` at run time.

The script runs fine manually, but when set as crontab

```
*/15 * * * * /log_parser/log.sh
```

it outputs an error `logger.xml missing`

How to set property files for jar while scheduling it via crontab?

Answer (score 1):

Pass argument to your shell script:

```
*/15 * * * * /log_parser/log.sh %LOGGER_XML_LOCATION%
```

or set the location of the xml file manually inside the shell script.

Pay attention that the current dir might differ when you run the script manually and when it runs by crontab.

Comment: tnx buddy..u said it rit
the pblm was due to diff in dir where the script runs manually and the dir where cron tab is set.
bt i hav to specify the path inside the java class to fix it..
passing argument to shell script didnt work out

Comment: @user767544, why don't you cd %LOG_XML_DIR% first thing in your shell script?